# show error for date(); function

Tags: php

I am using windows 7 (32 bit) and firefox 8.

When I used

```
"date(d m y);" function,
```

it shows yesterday's date rather showing today's date. Besides, when I used

```
"date(h.i.s);" function,
```

it should show 12.40.39 but it showing 6.40.39 and for

```
"date(H.i.s);"
```

showing 18.40.39 rather showing 24.40.39. Is it a configuring problem of my browser or something else?

Comment: Did you set your time-zone correctly in PHP?  This doesn't have anything to do with your browser.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual entry for date? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thank you guys for your replying. Now, I understand my problem.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line on top of your code to set your timezone correctly:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
?>
```

Comment: A lot of thaks Mr. anubhava :D. This is easy and 100% absolute.:):):)

Answer (score 1):

Just set your timezone http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php